# HorizontalPager loses its focus after a swipe gesture when TalkBack is enabled. only on Android 12

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, accessibility, talkback

I encountered an unusual bug specifically in Android version 12.

When swiping within a HorizontalPager in Compose, regardless of whether it contains images or simple text, the focus is unexpectedly lost. To regain focus, one must tap on the content within the HorizontalPager. It's worth noting that this issue does not occur on API levels 33 or 34.

Any suggestions, should I file a google bug report?

Comment: Yeah I think an issue tracker report would be good - if you share a link I'll +1 it too. Some advice: if you use scrcpy (https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) to record you can capture the audio as well - I think giving them a video might help demonstrate the problem better. The more specific you can be the easier it is for them to verify